# Fatal error: Call to undefined function xml_parser_create()

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am getting this error when I use to parse the xml content, I do have xml enabled in my localhost, And I have also checked xml reader, xml writer using php -m command. Can anyone tell me why its still showing?

Comment: which version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: @Deep , I have php5.6 installed

Comment: Show some code please.

Answer (score 0):

xml_parser_create() is part of the XML PHP module. If the function is undefined then it would probably be a problem with the way your XML module is installed on your SERVER.

You can check is it installed by phpinfo();

A post answered your question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/797469/php-5-6-undefined-function-xml-parser-create)

Comment: I have checked phpinfo() and php -m command, I can see xml enabled and I can also see these -- xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

Comment: i have same problem. php-xml is installed but i see this error